# Posting array using formdata

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, html, post

I am using the new HTML5 FormData-Object to post some values and an image via Ajax. It works fine so far. Now, I want to post an array using this object, but all I´ve got on server-side is "[object - object]". How can I post an array with formdata?

What I´ve got so far

```
var formData=new FormData();
formData.append('text', $('#text').attr('value'));
formData.append('headline',$('#headline').attr('value'));
formData.append('myarray',{key1: 'bla', key2: 'blubb'});
```

The last line doesn´t work. I send the request with this code

```
                 $.ajax({
                        url: 'xyz',
                        data: formData,
                        type: 'POST',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(data) { 
                            var decoded=$.parseJSON(data);
                            displaySuccess('Success', decoded.message); 
                        },error: function(data){
                            var decoded=$.parseJSON(data);
                            displayError('Error', decoded.message);
                        },complete: function(data){
                            $('#cursor').hide();
                            $("#submitbutton").removeAttr('disabled')
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your syntax, you appear to be trying to pass an object, not an array. I don't think you can pass objects through HTML form.

```
{ key1 : value1 , key2 : value2 }
```

**vs**

```
[ value1, value2 ]
```

This is a handy reference to general [JS syntax](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: yea you can pass objects ! give it a try with jquery's data field. just created a complex object and passed it and it kept the same structure on serverside

Comment: Hello @DanyKhalife how did you achieve that? I have similar problem.

Comment: @uikrosoft You can just pass the object as it is to jQuery. Let's say you have an object `var myData = {a: 1, b: 2, c: [3,4,5]};` the jQuery call will be something like  `$.ajax({ url: '/myscript.php', method: 'POST', data: myData, dataType: 'json', success: function(response){ console.log(response); } })`

Comment: hi @Bill i m also send array formData.append("ProIList", P.ProIList); in this but i don't getting server side this array list so can you know how can getting this list??

Answer (score 16):

Using `.append()` on each element of the associative array might produce the results you're expecting.

In place of this line:

```
formData.append('myarray',{key1: 'bla', key2: 'blubb'});
```

You might try the following:

```
var myarray = {key1: 'bla', key2: 'blubb'};

jQuery.each(myarray, function(key, value) {
    formData.append('myarray['+key+']', value);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks. I now came up with this solution:

```
                for (i = 0; i < social_networks.length; i++) {
                    formData.append("myarray["+i+"][mykey]",arr[i]['mykey']);
                    formData.append("myarray["+i+"][mykey2]",arr[i]['mykey2']);
                }
```

Comment: If you think that's the best answer, then you should accept it, to help others in future

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
var files = $scope.myFile;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", files[0]);
        fd.append("assignment", JSON.stringify({ classAssignment: $scope.editItem }));
```

Answer (score 0):

my arrary list is like this

```
billlists = [{ Color: "White"Quantity: "1"Shape: "2.0"SizeNo1: "1"SizeNo2: "1"StoneColorCost: "20000"StoneColorWT: "0.006"Type: "1"__proto__: Object1: Color: "White"Quantity: "1"Shape: "2.0"SizeNo1: "0.5"SizeNo2: "0.7"StoneColorCost: "6"StoneColorWT: "0.005"Type: "1"},

{ Color: "White"Quantity: "1"Shape: "2.0"SizeNo1: "1"SizeNo2: "1"StoneColorCost: "20000"StoneColorWT: "0.006"Type: "1"__proto__: Object1: Color: "White"Quantity: "1"Shape: "2.0"SizeNo1: "0.5"SizeNo2: "0.7"StoneColorCost: "6"StoneColorWT: "0.005"Type: "1"}]
```

**This code used to format data like key-value pairs**

```
function serializeData(name, arr)
 {
   var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
      for (var key in arr[i]) 
    {
 a.push({ name: name + '[' + i + '].' + key + '', value: arr[i][key] });
     }
        }
         return a;
                  }

  var mydata = serializeData('billlist', billlists);

  $.each(mydata, function (key, input) {
       fd.append(input.name, input.value);
            });
```

**This is output of serialized Data**

```
0: {name: "billlist[0].Type", value: "1"}
1: {name: "billlist[0].Color", value: "White"}
2: {name: "billlist[0].Shape", value: "2.0"}
3: {name: "billlist[0].SizeNo1", value: "1"}
4: {name: "billlist[0].SizeNo2", value: "1"}
5: {name: "billlist[0].Quantity", value: "1"}
6: {name: "billlist[0].StoneColorWT", value: "0.006"}
7: {name: "billlist[0].StoneColorCost", value: "20000"}
8: {name: "billlist[1].Type", value: "1"}
9: {name: "billlist[1].Color", value: "White"}
10: {name: "billlist[1].Shape", value: "2.0"}
11: {name: "billlist[1].SizeNo1", value: "0.5"}
12: {name: "billlist[1].SizeNo2", value: "0.7"}
13: {name: "billlist[1].Quantity", value: "1"}
14: {name: "billlist[1].StoneColorWT", value: "0.005"}
15: {name: "billlist[1].StoneColorCost", value: "6"}
```

**Its working for me**

**But in other post i seen data is pass like**

```
 {name: "billlist[0][Type]", value: "1"}
```

Way it not working for me